# Applying mortar to cinder block foundation to repair surface damage

Tags: repair, masonry, mortar, cinderblock

I have a cinder block foundation, and near the floor in my garage the parging has flaked off excessively, revealing cinder blocks with a poor surface.

My thought is to clean off any remaining parging that's flaky, clean the cinder blocks with a wire brush and apply mortar in any cracks and to the surface of the blocks.

From these pictures, would that be a valid solution, or must something else be done to repair the blocks?

Also, our (electric) dryer vents into the garage, which is why I assume the cinder blocks are in such poor shape compared to the rest of the house, but other potential causes may be good to know too.

Interior wall
[image: Interior wall overview]
[image: Interior wall detail]

Exterior wall
[image: Exterior wall overview]

Comment: I don't know enough, but some of those blocks seem to be quite rough looking, even if they are cinder blocks and not concrete/cement blocks.  Something to check before covering it over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **surface bonding cement** rather than plain mortar and your parging will do a bit more for you at basically the same cost and effort.

Your wall shows water (and freezing/spalling) damage. That probably is being aggravated by improperly venting dryer moisture into the garage, rather than outside, so you should correct that.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like good advice, I'm also looking to fix up the dryer vent as I'm fairly confident that's the root of my problem.